# How to show a cold pic when its cold and show a warm pic when its hot?

Tags: c#

Im using C# and i have to show a cold picture if the F or C is below 50F and a hot pic if the F or C is above 50F. i know i have to use an if statement but cant figure out how to write the if statement to show one pic or the other?

Comment: Is this in web forms, mvc, wpf, silverlight? Anything?

Comment: Pretty sure this needs a lot more detail. Is this winforms, webforms, MVC, silverlight, WPF?

Comment: Hi Nate! Do you know how to write a statement to show either picture? If you do, then check out the syntax for `if`. Think some about it!

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know a little more about what you're trying to accomplish. How are you showing the picture?

```
if(temp < 50)
    pictureSource = "cold.jpg";
else
    pictureSource = "hot.jpg";
```